# XML Dom for next stop looping after replacechild

Tags: php, xml, replace

Then i trying to use this code after first replacement loop is stoping
`$Autos->length = 10`

```
$Autos = $dom->getElementsByTagName('cars'); // Find Sections 
$NewElement = $dom->createElement('hello','hi');
for ($i = 0; $i < $Autos->length; $i++) 
{

    $Autos->item($i)->parentNode->replaceChild($NewElement, $Autos->item($i));
    echo $Autos->length . " i= " .$i;
}
```

so $i always = 0 
why this hapens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOMNode::getElementsByTagName() returns a "live" list. It changes if the document is changed. You replace the node, so the list changes, too.

Here are three ways to solve this problem.

1. Cast the node list into an array:

   `$Autos = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('cars'));`
2. Loop the list from the last node to the first:

   `for ($i = $Autos->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {`
3. Use XPath to fetch the nodes:

   `$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);`
   `$Autos = $xpath->evaluate('//cars');`

XPath expressions are a lot more flexible and powerful then the DOM methods to fetch nodes and the results are not 'live'. For example you can do something like:

```
$Autos = $xpath->evaluate('//cars[@manufacturer = "SomeCompanyName"]');
```

Here is another problem in you source. You replace the node with only a single created node. So it replaces the first node, then the same node replaces the second node, ... until it replaces the last node in the list.

You will need to clone the created node:

```
$Autos->item($i)->parentNode->replaceChild(
  $NewElement->cloneNode(TRUE), $Autos->item($i)
);
```

Node lists implement the Traversable interface. You can use foreach().

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//cars') as $i => $car) {
  $car->parentNode->replaceChild($NewElement->cloneNode(TRUE), $car);
  echo " i= " .$i;
}
```

As a side note. It is often easier to build a new target XML document and copy the nodes to it then to manipulate an existing document. XSLT is a specific language just for this task.